# Joining tables to create a total sum of two seperate orders

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get the cost of each item over to a final table where it only shows the final ORDER_ID and the ORDER_TOTAL. I am having issues getting my two tables to join and am struggling with JOIN as a whole. These are the two tables that I am trying to join.

ORDER COST

```
CREATE TABLE `order cost` (
  `ORDER_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `MENU_COST` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `ORDER_COST` double(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `order cost` (`ORDER_ID`, `MENU_COST`, `ORDER_COST`) VALUES
(1, 7.00, 7.63),
(3, 8.00, 8.72),
(1, 13.00, 14.17),
(3, 25.00, 27.25);


ALTER TABLE `order cost`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_COST`),
  ADD KEY `ORDER_ID` (`ORDER_ID`),
  ADD KEY `MENU_COST` (`MENU_COST`);
```

ORDER TOTAL

```
CREATE TABLE `order total` (
  `ORDER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ORDER_TOTAL` double(6,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `order total` (`ORDER_ID`, `ORDER_TOTAL`) VALUES
(1, 0.00),
(3, 0.00);


ALTER TABLE `order total`
  ADD KEY `ORDER_ID` (`ORDER_ID`);
```

My join code attempt:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID,
SUM(MENU_COST) = ORDER_TOTAL 
FROM `order cost`
INNER JOIN `order total`
GROUP BY ORDER_ID;
```

I have tried multiple other join ideas, and in the main order cost table I was able to get the SUMS(ORDER_COST) to create its own cell after I ran a

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, SUM(MENU_COST) FROM `order cost` GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

But this creates its own table after the run, whereas I am looking to get the table to auto produce in the 'order total' based on changes to the database.

Comment: Your INNER JOIN lacks an ON clause set. Are you aware that it is required? Do you know how to write it?

Comment: No clue how to write it but I have seen examples I will attempt and post if I have it

Comment: May I also suggest that you just skip the notion of having the order total table entirely.. any time you want to know the order total add it up from the order cost table, rather than having to constantly maintain the order total table to be in sync with the sum of the costs. Is this an academic exercise?

Comment: Yes, i have multiple tables to practice relational databases, in particular for a food ordering database. I have all my other tables linked and set up properly, this final output of the total is my last hangup. I might be trying to do more than I need to as the order_total is my own doing. But when the instructor sees the work I want her to see the end result which would be a final cost. I could probably get away with not having total cost

Comment: If you want a final cost, just use the SUM/GROUP BY query you already have..

Comment: Do not put spaces in table names

Answer (score 0):

See comments above for my thoughts on not doing this. You'll have to run this query every time you make a change to the ordercost table:

```
UPDATE 
  ordertotal 
SET
  order_total = (
    SELECT SUM(MENU_COST) FROM ordercost WHERE ORDER_ID = x GROUP BY ORDER_ID
  )
WHERE order_id = x
```

There is no joining here.. you insert some new item to ordercost and then run the query to sync the table. On the whole it's a terrible idea. You should consider instead creating a VIEW and selecting from it when needed:

```
CREATE VIEW ordertotal AS
SELECT 
  ORDER_ID,
  SUM(MENU_COST) as ORDER_TOTAL 
FROM ordercost
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

It will behave like a table:

```
SELECT * FROM ordertotal where order_id = 3
```